# Any way to stream a map like "(k,v)" instead of working with (entry)?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Basically I look for a way to avoid working with

```
entry -> entry.getValue
```

and

```
entry -> entry.getKey
```

similar to what `Map.forEach()` does.

If only I could get a way to work as `map.stream().filter((k,v) -> )`... and so on

It seems the interface is called BiConsumer.
Perhaps with a converter to BiConsumer or a Stream.generate() someway

Comment: Can you be more explicit. Probably post an example.

Comment: There isn't any way, as you can easily figure out from the API of `Map`. But what's wrong with `entrySet()` approach?

Comment: I have to execute i.getEntry and i.getKey a lot of times

Comment: There isn't any API to get `stream` from a map directly. You've to get it through `entrySet()` or `keySet()`. Former would be more easy to work with. If you're having `getKey()` and `getValue()` a lot of times, then possible you can avoid lambdas altogether. Rest can be suggested only after seeing the actual scenario.

Comment: Okay, perhaps converting the entryset Set into a biconsumer stream? or either use Stream.generate someway?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since this is a repeating question, I will throw a full solution into the ring. It’s a `PairStream` type that is by default a simple wrapper around an ordinary `Stream` (though, being an `interface`, alternatives are possible).

It focuses on providing the convenient intermediate operations and those terminal operations which can not be easily performed by calling one of the methods `keys()`, `values()` or `entries()` to return to a conventional single-element `Stream` and chain a terminal operation. So for example, `PairStream.from(map).filterValue(predicate).keys().findAny()` is the straight-forward way to get a key for which the mapped value matches the predicate. `filterValue` is a convenience intermediate operation and `keys` turn back to an ordinary `Stream` allowing an arbitrary terminal operation for the keys.

Some examples

```
    Map<String,Integer> m=new HashMap<>();
    m.put("foo", 5);
    m.put("bar", 7);
    m.put("baz", 42);
    // {b=49, f=5}
    Map<Character,Integer> m2=PairStream.from(m)
      .mapKey(s->s.charAt(0))
      .toMap(Integer::sum);

    // foo bar
    String str=PairStream.from(m)
      .filterValue(i->i<30)
      .keys().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

```
    Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    map.put("muhv~", 26);
    map.put("kfool", 3);
    String str = PairStream.from(map)
      .sortedByValue(Comparator.naturalOrder())
      .flatMapToInt((s,i)->s.codePoints().map(c->c^i))
      .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
      .toString();
```

Here is the complete class (I haven’t tested all operations, however most of it is straight-forward):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public interface PairStream<K,V> {
    static <K,V> PairStream<K,V> from(Map<K,V> map) {
        return from(map.entrySet().stream());
    }
    static <K,V> PairStream<K,V> from(Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> s) {
        return ()->s;
    }
    static <K,V> PairStream<K,V> from(Stream<K> s, Function<? super K, ? extends V> f) {
        return ()->s.map(k->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(k, f.apply(k)));
    }

    default PairStream<K,V> distinct() {
        return from(entries().distinct());
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> peek(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        return from(entries().peek(e->action.accept(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> skip(long n) {
        return from(entries().skip(n));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> limit(long maxSize) {
        return from(entries().limit(maxSize));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> filterKey(Predicate<? super K> mapper) {
        return from(entries().filter(e->mapper.test(e.getKey())));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> filterValue(Predicate<? super V> mapper) {
        return from(entries().filter(e->mapper.test(e.getValue())));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> filter(BiPredicate<? super K, ? super V> mapper) {
        return from(entries().filter(e->mapper.test(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));
    }
    default <R> PairStream<R,V> mapKey(Function<? super K,? extends R> mapper) {
        return from(entries().map(e->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
            mapper.apply(e.getKey()), e.getValue()
        )));
    }
    default <R> PairStream<K,R> mapValue(Function<? super V,? extends R> mapper) {
        return from(entries().map(e->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
            e.getKey(), mapper.apply(e.getValue())
        )));
    }
    default <R> Stream<R> map(BiFunction<? super K, ? super V,? extends R> mapper) {
        return entries().map(e->mapper.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default DoubleStream mapToDouble(ToDoubleBiFunction<? super K, ? super V> mapper) {
        return entries().mapToDouble(e->mapper.applyAsDouble(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default IntStream mapToInt(ToIntBiFunction<? super K, ? super V> mapper) {
        return entries().mapToInt(e->mapper.applyAsInt(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default LongStream mapToLong(ToLongBiFunction<? super K, ? super V> mapper) {
        return entries().mapToLong(e->mapper.applyAsLong(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default <RK,RV> PairStream<RK,RV> flatMap(
            BiFunction<? super K, ? super V,? extends PairStream<RK,RV>> mapper) {
        return from(entries().flatMap(
            e->mapper.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()).entries()));
    }
    default <R> Stream<R> flatMapToObj(
            BiFunction<? super K, ? super V,? extends Stream<R>> mapper) {
        return entries().flatMap(e->mapper.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default DoubleStream flatMapToDouble(
            BiFunction<? super K, ? super V,? extends DoubleStream> mapper) {
        return entries().flatMapToDouble(e->mapper.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default IntStream flatMapToInt(
            BiFunction<? super K, ? super V,? extends IntStream> mapper) {
        return entries().flatMapToInt(e->mapper.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default LongStream flatMapToLong(
            BiFunction<? super K, ? super V,? extends LongStream> mapper) {
        return entries().flatMapToLong(e->mapper.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> sortedByKey(Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
        return from(entries().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(comparator)));
    }
    default PairStream<K,V> sortedByValue(Comparator<? super V> comparator) {
        return from(entries().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(comparator)));
    }

    default boolean allMatch(BiPredicate<? super K,? super V> predicate) {
        return entries().allMatch(e->predicate.test(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default boolean anyMatch(BiPredicate<? super K,? super V> predicate) {
        return entries().anyMatch(e->predicate.test(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default boolean noneMatch(BiPredicate<? super K,? super V> predicate) {
        return entries().noneMatch(e->predicate.test(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default long count() {
        return entries().count();
    }

    Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> entries();
    default Stream<K> keys() {
        return entries().map(Map.Entry::getKey);
    }
    default Stream<V> values() {
        return entries().map(Map.Entry::getValue);
    }
    default Optional<Map.Entry<K,V>> maxByKey(Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
        return entries().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(comparator));
    }
    default Optional<Map.Entry<K,V>> maxByValue(Comparator<? super V> comparator) {
        return entries().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(comparator));
    }
    default Optional<Map.Entry<K,V>> minByKey(Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
        return entries().min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(comparator));
    }
    default Optional<Map.Entry<K,V>> minByValue(Comparator<? super V> comparator) {
        return entries().min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(comparator));
    }
    default void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        entries().forEach(e->action.accept(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }
    default void forEachOrdered(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        entries().forEachOrdered(e->action.accept(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }

    default Map<K,V> toMap() {
        return entries().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
    default Map<K,V> toMap(BinaryOperator<V> valAccum) {
        return entries().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, valAccum));
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot find the interface `PariStream` in Java SE 1.8 documentation. Is this interface from another API?

Comment: @mark42inbound the complete definition of `PairStream` is right at the end of this answer.

Comment: I see. So it's a utility interface. I was hoping that it might be part of Java.

Comment: @mark42inbound unfortunately not. As said in the beginning of this answer, the call for such a feature is a repeating one. But even Java 10 has no such feature.

Comment: It's a gem of an answer! Thanks

Answer (score 21):

It's a bit unfortunate that the main way to process a map using streams is to stream the map's entries. That means you have to extracting the entries' keys and values. This is somewhat verbose, but it isn't really all that bad. Still, it might be reasonable to consider some kind of helper methods that will adapt a `BiPredicate` or `BiFunction` so that they can be used in the `filter` or `map` stages of a stream of map entries. They look like this:

```
static <K,V> Predicate<Map.Entry<K,V>> p(BiPredicate<? super K, ? super V> bip) {
    return entry -> bip.test(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

static <K,V,R> Function<Map.Entry<K,V>,R> m(BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, R> bif) {
    return entry -> bif.apply(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Once you have these, you can use them to simplify(?) a map entry stream. Let's say you have a `Map<String,Integer>` and you want to select the entries where the string key's length is greater than the integer value, and then format the key and value into a string. Conventionally you'd do this:

```
    map.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(e -> e.getKey().length() > e.getValue())
                  .map(e -> e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue())
                  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

With the helper functions above, you could rewrite this pipeline as:

```
    map.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(p((k, v) -> k.length() > v))
                  .map(m((k, v) -> k + ":" + v))
                  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

OK, you save a few characters. Is it worth it?

Comment: It's certainly worth it, because you can name the lambda parameters something else than "key" and "value" which leads to better self documenting code.

Answer (score 9):

No, there's no way to do this; `Stream` only works with a single element type.  There's no way around the `getKey` and `getValue` approach.

(Streaming over the keys and calling `get` doesn't actually seem to be any better from your perspective, and it's likely to be strictly less efficient.)

Answer (score 3):

To only change values but keep the keys, using guavas Maps.transformEntries:

```
Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("foo", 5);
m.put("bar", 7);
m.put("baz", 42);

Map newMapView = Maps.transformEntries(m, (k, v) -> k + ":" + v);
```

Else to change keys and values of a Map (At the risk of colliding keys), it is possible to write Util functions:

```
public static <K, V, K2, V2> Stream<Map.Entry<K2, V2>> transformationStream(Map<K, V> input, BiFunction<K, V, Map.Entry<K2, V2>> entryTransformer) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> entryTransformer.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
}

public static <K, V, K2, V2> Map<K2, V2> transformMap(Map<K, V> input, BiFunction<K, V, Map.Entry<K2, V2>> entryTransformer) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> entryTransformer.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}

public static <K, V, K2, V2> Map<K2, V2> transformMap(Map<K, V> input, BiFunction<K, V, Map.Entry<K2, V2>> entryTransformer, BinaryOperator<V2> combiner) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> entryTransformer.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, combiner));
}
```

It's likely the typical util libraries like Guava do not provide those because of the complexities of potential key collisions in the resulting Map.