# Map key value to an object in Java 8 stream

Tags: java, constructor, java-8, mapping, java-stream

Let's say I have this code:

```
Map<String, String> map;
// later on
map.entrySet().stream().map(MyObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And I have a `MyObject` `Constructor` which takes two arguments of type `String`.
I want to be able to do this but I cannot. 
I know I can do `e -> new MyObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue())` but prefer `MyObject::new`.

Similar code works for `Set<String>` and `List<String>` with one argument constructor of `MyObject` class.

Comment: the ``map`` function is not aware that the 2 necessary ``String``s are somewhere inside that ``Map.Entry`` instance. You have to manually extract key and value, thus you need to use ``e.getKey()`` and ``e.getValue()``.

Comment: Why do you prefer a method reference? It's elegant when it fits the requirements, but here it doesn't.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835382/use-method-reference-with-parameter)

Comment: You can use the `PairStream` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29254246/2711488); `PairStream.from(map).map(MyObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 10):

use a lambda:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .map(e -> new MyObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

otherwise the only way to use a method reference is by creating a function as such:

```
private static MyObject apply(Map.Entry<String, String> e) {
      return new MyObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

then do something like:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .map(Main::apply)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `Main` is the class containing the `apply` method.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> map.entrySet().stream().map(MyObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
> ```
>
> And I have a `MyObject` Constructor which takes two arguments of type `String`. I want to be able to do this but I cannot.

In `map.entrySet().stream().map(...)`, Java is expecting a `Function`,
mapping one value to another value.
One value.
From the stream, the function receives a value of type `Map.Entry<String, String>`,
but your constructor takes two `String` arguments.
Java doesn't automagically expand a `Map.Entry<String, String>` to a pair of `String`s to pass to your constructor.
You have to do that unwrapping manually.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the constructor is that it defines two parameters, while [`Function#apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#apply(T)) demanded by [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) accepts only one.

You could write a static factory method for `MyObject`

```
class MyObject {
    public static MyObject of(Map.Entry<String, String> e) {
        return new MyObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

and refer to it like

```
map(MyObject::of)
```

*Before you do so, ask yourself if one pretty-looking line in a plain processing chain somewhere is worthy of a new constructor or utility method.*

Answer (score 2):

#### Add a Map.Entry constructor

```
class MyObject {
        private final String k;
        private final String v;

        MyObject(String s1, String s2) {
            k = s1;
            v = s2;
        }

        MyObject(Map.Entry<String, String> e) {
            this(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "key: " + k + ' ' + "value: " + v;
        }
    }
```

You will be able to call

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = map.entrySet().stream().map(MyObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```