# Is there a way to apply a function with multiple parameters to a stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

I have the following generic method for transforming a page object into a `Slice`:

```
public static <T,R> Slice<R> toSlice(final Page<T> source, Function<T,R> transform) {
  return Slice.<R>builder()
      .totalPages(BigInteger.valueOf(source.getTotalPages()))
      .pageData(source.stream()
          .map(transform)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
      .build();
}
```

I would then use this as follows:

```
return SliceFactory.toSlice(
            someDao.findAll(
                    predicate,
                    PageRequest.of(page, PAGE_SIZE,
                        Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, DEFAULT_SORTING_PROPERTY))),
            dtoFactory::toSomeDto);
```

However, I would like to now pass an additional argument to `dtoFactory.toSomeDto()`. I'm not sure how can I turn this into a generic method, similar to the existing `toSlice()` method?

Comment: So…just use a lambda expression?

Comment: You could probably look into using a BiFunction, however stream().map() only takes a Function.

You will need to use something else, other than map() if you want to alter the state of the stream content based on (2) values at a time.

`public static <T,R,V> Slice<R> toSlice(final Page<T> source, BiFunction<T,R,V> transform) { }`

Comment: @JCompetence that is exactly my issue. Is there anything else that I can use instead of map?

Comment: @Holger I believe you mentioned it first. But even after reading your comment, I didn't think of just passing a lambda expression as an argument.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it with `param -> dtoFactory.toSomeDto(param, additionalParam)` but in that case you have to ensure that `additionalParam` is effectively immutable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) to do this.

Assuming that `dtoFactory` is an instance of `DtoFactory`, then the code

```
dtoFactory::toSomeDto
```

is really referring to a class method

```
public class DtoFactory {
    public R toSomeDto( T t ) { .... } // Function<T,R>
}
```

What the `::` syntax is doing, is turning your normal method into a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). A `Function` takes one argument and returns one. A `BiFunction` takes two arguments.

To illustrate, this is valid code which compiles, and which prints

```
ab
[x1, x2, x3]
A123
```

---

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Test test = new Test();
        BiFunction<String,String,String> b = test::bifunc;
        System.out.println( b.apply( "a", "b" ) );
        System.out.println( Stream.of( 1, 2, 3 )
            .map( (i) -> test.bifunc( "x", i.toString() ) )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
        System.out.println( Stream.of( 1, 2, 3 )
            .map( (i) -> i.toString() )
            .reduce( "A", test::bifunc ) );
    }

    public String bifunc( String one, String two ) {
        return one + two;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but then I can't use map.

Comment: @benjaminv2  Of course you can. I'll amend the `reduce` example to show this.

Comment: @benjaminv2  `map()` is for transforming. It takes a `Function`. If you want to use `map()` with a `BiFunction` you've got to think about where your 2nd argument is coming from. That's why I included the `reduce()` example.  You can create a `Function` which wraps your `BiFunction` and which knows where your 2nd arg is coming from.

Comment: @benjaminv2 Also see this question, see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239377/any-way-to-stream-a-map-like-k-v-instead-of-working-with-entry

Comment: I understand. However a much simpler approach (thanks to cyberbrains comment above) is to just use the lambda function when passing it as a parameter to the toSlice method. That solves the issue for me. I completely overlooked this.

Comment: @benjaminv2  Exactly. Same as the line in my example `.map( (i) -> test.bifunc( "x", i.toString() ) )`, where `"x"` is the additional argument  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it as the following below:  Your other (variable) which you require to affect the result of map, needs to be an external variable, and not a Function<> input:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String anotherVariableThatAlters = "HelloWorld";

    Function<String,String> defaultFunction = (stringFromStream) -> {
        return stringFromStream + "_" + anotherVariableThatAlters;
    };

    System.out.println(Stream.of("1", "2", "3").map(defaultFunction).collect(Collectors.toList()));

}
```

---

```
[1_HelloWorld, 2_HelloWorld, 3_HelloWorld]
```

Comment: Which is basically [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

Comment: @Michael I learned a new word :) thx